# Display check box selections in one string (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net

Trying to get the results of all selected items to display in one message box string. I have this so far, which I know is wrong. If it matters, this list is filled via a text file and objects.

```
Dim cBike As String = "
    For Each cBike In clbBikes.Items
        cBike = clbBikes.SelectedItem & ", "
    Next
    MsgBox(("Your selection of: " & cBike))
```

Help please, my lecturer is taking forever and helping those who need it more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably meant `CheckedItems`:

```
 Dim cBike As String = ""
 For Each chk As String In clbBikes.CheckedItems
    cBike &= chk & ", "
 Next

 MessageBox.Show("Your selection of: " & cBike)
```

Comment: Glad that it work for you @user2981644. You can accept my answer by clicking on the check mark on the left side. Happy coding and GOD bless.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually concatenate the strings:

```
For Each cBike In clbBikes.Items
    cBike = cBike + clbBikes.SelectedItem & ", "
Next
```

You need to then also remove the last comma

```
If (xml.Length > 2) Then
    cBike = cBike.Remove(cBike.Length - 2, 2)
End If
```